# Как в Yii задается Get параметр общий для всех контроллеров?

Tags: yii

В правилах маршрутизации как установить чтобы параметр id был для всех контроллеров

чтоб общее правило было

/id/1

/catalog/id/1

/catalog/book/id/1

/catalog/film/id/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/id/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```